# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable Can't figure this out

Tags: python, typeerror

I tried writing some code but when I ran it, it returned the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable":

This is the line of code:

```
if data[key][0] == b[0] and data[key][1] == b[1]:
```

'data' is a dictionary with 'key' being the key and '0' being the value (before the 'and')

I just need to know why this is happening and how it can be fixed. Thanks :)

**Example of code**

```
data = {
'a' : ['1','1'],
'b' : ['1','2'],
'c' : ['1','3'],
'd' : ['1','4'],
'e' : ['1','5'],
'f' : ['2','1'],
'g' : ['2','2'],
'h' : ['2','3'],
'i' : ['2','4'],
'j' : ['2','4'],
'k' : ['2','5'],
'l' : ['3','1'],
'm' : ['3','2'],
'n' : ['3','3'],
'o' : ['3','4'],
'p' : ['3','5'],
'q' : ['4','1'],
'r' : ['4','2'],
's' : ['4','3'],
't' : ['4','4'],
'u' : ['4','5'],
'v' : ['5','1'],
'w' : ['5','2'],
'x' : ['5','3'],
'y' : ['5','4'],
'z' : ['5','5']
}


total = '21333534313511424214'
count = 0 
b = []
finalOuput = []
for number in total:
    if count == 2:
        for number in b:
            for key in data:
                if data[key][0] == b[0] and data[key][1] == b[1]:
                    finalOutput.append(b[0])
                    finalOutput.append(b[1])
                    count = 0
                    b = 0
                    total.replace(number,'')
                else:
                    continue
    else:
        b.append(number)
        count += 1
        continue
```

Comment: You should probably look at the values of `data['key']` and `b` in whatever debugger you use...

Comment: Either `data[key]` is an integer, or `b` is an integer.

Comment: _and '0' being the value_ I think you may be confused.  `x[0]` means x is a sequence (such as a list or a tuple), and you're asking for the first value in that sequence.  0 does not indicate a literal value...

Comment: What's the output of `type(data)` and `type(b)`?

Comment: If `data[key] = 0` then `data[key][0]` is the same as `0[0]` ... and that clearly is a problem. Do `print(repr(data[key]))` so we know for sure what its value is.

Comment: The output of type(data) is <class 'dict'> and the output of type(b) is <class 'list'>.

Comment: print(repr(data[key])) returns:    ['3', '2']
['2', '2']
['4', '1']
['1', '4']
['5', '5']
['4', '3']
['5', '2']
['4', '4']
['1', '5']
['4', '5']
['2', '4']
['4', '2']
['3', '3']
['2', '3']
['2', '4']
['2', '1']
['1', '3']

Comment: If `b` is a list, then the problem must be with `data[key]`.  That `repr()` output doesn't look like any data type I'm familiar with.  Can you post the output of `print(type(data[key]))`?

Comment: @JohnGordon - I think that's the list printed multiple times in a loop.

Comment: Assuming `data = {"key": ['3', '2']}`, `key = "key"` and `b = ['3', '2']`, I'm unable to reproduce your error... Like @JohnGordon notes, the problem should be in the values of your dictionary.

Comment: You could wrap that line in a try/except block and then print out current values just for the case where it fails. Inside the `except TypeError:` you would `print(repr(data[key]), repr(b))` then we'd see more details of the exact failure state.

Comment: @tdelaney He said it was the literal output of `print(repr(data[key]))`, so something is fishy.  Maybe it's a Numpy array or something?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to figure this out. Can you post a runnable example that demonstrates the problem? We don't know what's in these variables and we don't know if that line of code is in a loop which has us making wild guesses.

Comment: @JohnGordon - If the code we see is in a loop and it printed multiple lines (`['3', '2']\n['2', '2']\n...`) it would look like this when pasted into a comment.

Comment: @tdelaney I'll get an example now for you.

Comment: @tdelaney Added to original post.

Comment: `b = 0` you're replacing the original list `b` with a single integer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. Changing that     b = 0     mistake fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have redefined `b` from a `list` to `int` hence it cant be indexed.

Relevant excerpt from your code:

```
if data[key][0] == b[0] and data[key][1] == b[1]:
    finalOuput.append(b[0])
    finalOutput.append(b[1])
    count = 0

    ## b has been redefined as 0 hence `b[0]` causes error ##
    b = 0     

    total.replace(number,'')
else:
    continue
```